# Android (Emulator) Socket Permission denied on 10.0.0.2 (same machine)

Tags: java, sockets, android-studio, emulation, permission-denied

_Hello everybody, my name is Tobi, I'm a qualified experienced java developer for 7 years.
I usually google up and down the internet even for days and try different things to find my solution - but right now, I'm near to a psychosis because even I'm good enough to write pc applications for java, I'm obviously way too dumb to do same for android apps.

All i want to do is to establish a socket connection to the local machine which runs the Emulator in android studio, too.

I will now list things up what works, what i tried, and so on. Code isn't THAT necessary because it's WORKING code from a java example and all i did was to fit it to android. I surely will forget some things because it's so many things to regcognize, so please if you miss something, just ask and i will add it.

- Connection task is in AsyncTask class and called from the activity with ".execute"
- I tried everything to connect the ip (10.0.0.2, localhost, 127.0.0.1, 172.16.1.184...)
- Port is 9898 and freed in firewall.
- It's hardcoded (ip and port) in the doInBackground method
- I added  to my manifest and YES i did it outside application tag!
- I also restarted or updated firewall, even when the java client still worked fine
- The java server initiates a welcome message or problems message when a client connects. In this case (android) it does NOTHING.
- Everything you can imagine is surrounded with try/catch... IDE doesn't leave you alone with this...

I don't know what to list else... I just at least know one thing right now: Networking with android (emulator) is complete bullshit because google defines strong rules but gives no good opportunity to shut them off for any reason.

If you want to see any code pieces, please ask for it, too. But, i say again, don't expect something special. Normally, it's pushover.

Please, any good android developer, HELP ME!!!

Ah, sorry, here is the Android Monitor output:

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gINEF.png)

Thanks in advance and kind regards

Tobi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it.

I found a list with all(?) "uses-permissions" and cleared it from the system-app-based and deprecated ones. If you have any problems like mine, insert this list as first tag after "package" in your manifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_PACKAGE_SIZE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_FORMAT_FILESYSTEMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_STATS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REORDER_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ALARM" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ALWAYS_FINISH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ANIMATION_SCALE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_PROCESS_LIMIT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME_ZONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SIGNAL_PERSISTENT_PROCESSES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SUBSCRIBED_FEEDS_READ" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SUBSCRIBED_FEEDS_WRITE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_SIP" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
```